# How to post the data in encoding structure?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using two models GET and POST which are encodable and decodable

using the below code i am able to get the data in GET model, but i am not able to post the data with POST model.

please guide me how to post the data using POST model

```
let url = URL(string: "<YOUR URL HERE>")
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
config.httpAdditionalHeaders = [
"Accept" : "application/json",
"Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
]

let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
request.encodeParameters(parameters: ["username": username, "password": 
password])

let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
guard let data = data else { return }
  do {
      let sentPost = try JSONDecoder().decode(Get.self, from: data)
      print(sentPost)
  } catch {}
}
task.resume()
```

model

```
struct Post: Encodable, Decodable {
    let username: String
    let password: String
}
```

extension for URLRequest

```
extension URLRequest {

private func percentEscapeString(_ string: String) -> String {
    var characterSet = CharacterSet.alphanumerics
    characterSet.insert(charactersIn: "-._* ")

    return string
        .addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: characterSet)!
        .replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+", options: [], range: nil)
}

mutating func encodeParameters(parameters: [String : String]) {
    httpMethod = "POST"

    let parameterArray = parameters.map { (arg) -> String in
        let (key, value) = arg
        return "\(key)=\(self.percentEscapeString(value))"
    }

    httpBody = parameterArray.joined(separator: "&").data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your model?

Comment: Can you please clean up the code in the question, i.e. properly indent and structure it. It looks like it consists of a class and a separate code fragment. If so, make it obvious. If you expect help from other people, do not make it unnecessarily hard for them to understand the problem and code.

Comment: Instead of creating a & separated string, try to post the entire dictionary as data instead. If you debug on the server side, can you see any data being sent?

Comment: @Codo, i have cleaned the code, would you please help now

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to create another string and then to data. This will be handled by `Codable` protocol and your `JSONEncoder`. You need to encode your post type using `JSONEncoder` and provide the data to the `request.httpBody`

Try this:

```
let url = URL(string: "<YOUR URL HERE>")
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
config.httpAdditionalHeaders = [
    "Accept" : "application/json",
    "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
]

do {
    let aPost = Post(username: "username", password: "password")
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let encodedPost = try encoder.encode(aPost)

    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = encodedPost

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        do {
            let sentPost = try JSONDecoder().decode(Get.self, from: data)
            print(sentPost)
        } catch { 
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @nayem, after using the above code, i am getting error as **"The data couldn’t be read because it is missing."**

Comment: Then it's some other issue. Put a breakpoint inside the completion handler of `dataTask..` function and investigate the issue. Maybe your decoding isn't correct or your server doesn't send you data

Comment: Sure let me try that, but i was getting the data before, I am still getting the data if i dont use your code just i am not able to use the Post model with mine

Comment: Yes, investigate. You can try `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` to see what's actually returning from the API.

Comment: Optional("{\"error\":\"unsupported_grant_type\"}")
is the error, since i am POSTing  application/x-www-form-urlencoded not JSON